# create interface for different databases, propeties for choice implementation

Tags: java, sql, xml, interface

I want to create interface for different databases XML, Sql and implementations. I have one interface but it  is good for xml, but for other ? I want to create jar libary from this interface. Also I have a POJO class Book which represent object from database. I will have two implementations, one for XML, one for sql, how should I do to set one from propeties file without compilation ?

```
 interface DataInterface {

public void setBook(ArrayList<Book> book);

public ArrayList<Book> getBook();

public void update(ArrayList<Book> book, int row, int col);

public void read();

public void add(Book book);
   }
```

Comment: You'd need some kind of manager that could read the properties file, find and locate the "implementation" (probably through Class.forName) and return the implementation of the common interface

Comment: Have you considered using spring for your dependency injection?  You could change the implementation in the spring xml configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create 2 classes viz `XmlDataInterface` and `SqlDataInterface` both of which implement your given interface `DataInterface`.

Now wherever you want to access the interface, you have a reference of `DataInterface`, and access all of the above mentioned methods. This way, the code that uses `DataInterface` remains unaware of the implementation details.

---

The tricky part comes when you are instantiating it. :)

You can have a file like `your_file_name.properties` and have something like

> DataInterfaceImplementationType = XML (OR SQL)

stored in it.

You can easily access it as a key-value pair (for details, refer java.util.Properties).

The only thing remains now is actual instantiation which should be something similar to

```
DataInterface dataInterface; // Declare as a member.
// Use it everywhere freely without worrying.


// In maybe a constructor put following.

String dataInterfaceImplementationValue;

// Code to read properties file and get value of dataInterfaceImplementationValue.

if (dataInterfaceImplementationValue.equals("XML")) {
    dataInterface = new XmlDataInterface();
} else if (dataInterfaceImplementationValue.equals("SQL") {
    dataInterface = new SqlDataInterface();
} else {
    System.out.println("Invalid property set: " + dataInterfaceImplementationValue);
}
```

Hope this helps.